# Minecraft Better Together Servers on Xbox One

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

Do you need Xbox Live Gold to access servers?

Comment: We can't answer the second part; we don't allow questions about unreleased games.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: Any online gameplay for ANY game on the Xbox Line of Consoles requires Xbox Live

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need Xbox Live Gold.

> Do I need an Xbox Live Gold subscription to play Minecraft online?
>
> You will need an Xbox Live Gold subscription (sold separately) to use
>   the following online features within Minecraft:
>
> - Realms
> - Connecting to servers
> - Cross-platform play
>
> For local multiplayer you will not need an Xbox Live Gold
>   subscription.

[Source](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-titles/minecraft-better-together-update)